# command to convert pdf to eps with no loss in resolution

Tags: images, pdf, osx-snow-leopard

I want to convert a .pdf file to an .eps file of the same resolution on a unix based machine. If I use

"pdf2ps file.pdf file.eps"

the resulting .eps image is not the same as the .pdf image. Colors are much lighter as compared to the .pdf one. Also, the size of file.pdf is 115 KB, and that of file.eps is 3.6 MB.

Can someone please guide me how to properly convert a .pdf file to .eps file. I am using Mac OSX Snow-leopard (10.6.8).

Thanks
M

Comment: Could use something like Adobe Reader and "print" the file to virtual PostScript printer and capture the output?

Comment: Thanks @martineau! Opening the .pdf file in preview and printing it as postscript file works. I have some 100 .pdf files that I want to convert to .eps files, I will have to find a command line option to do this job. Do you have any pointers about that?

Comment: You could automate it using AppleScript or write a script for one of the Unix shells, like `bash`. There should be an AppleScript Editor application in your Utilities folder and there are many tutorials for it around on the Web. Snow-Leopard also has something called the _Automator_ which will write AppleScripts for you -- it's sort of like a macro generator. Of course there's lots of information about Unix shell script programming on the Web, too.

Comment: @shadowfax: Could you maybe accept the answer to mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend looking at [this question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/how-to-convert-pdf-to-eps), but to summarize the part I used to do the same thing is:

```
pdftops -eps filename.pdf
```

Comment: Huh, this was definitely a lossy compression for me!